# How do I transpose the function symbols in a parent and child sexp?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

What I have:

```
(abs (/ total 2))
```

What I'm looking for:

```
(/ (abs total) 2)
```

I'm pretty sure there's a command in emacs for that, although I can't find one in docs. If it matters, I use spacemacs.

Answer (score 0):

sp-convolute-sexp from the smartparens package would *almost* do it.

It can transform

```
(abs (/ |total 2))
```

to

```
(/ (abs |total 2))
```

(where | is the point)

But it's not aware of the unary / binary difference between "abs" and "/".
Maybe that function is a starting point for a solution?

Comment: I ended up doing paredit-convolute-sexp and then sp-dedent-adjust-sexp, which gives `(/ (abs total )2)`, which is ugly but very close. Still looking for suggestions.